# iOS webview copy action doesn't work

Tags: ios, webview, copy-paste

I made a app using UIWebview.

By the way, there is a problem in webview.

some page(in webview) can use copy and paste action.

But, some other page(in webview) doesn't work copy and paste action.(also another action doesn't work)

(all of page use same UIWebview in my code.)

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: can you show me both codes for the uiwebview?

Comment: uiwebview is same. the different is only webpage. I think my word is can noise. I just edit my text.